# Linux command to get current value of java.io.tmpdir

Tags: unix, properties, command, system

I need a Linux command to get current value of java.io.tmpdir
Also can you tell me the command to get all the system propeties.

Comment: do you mean environment variables by "system properties"?

Answer (score 36):

JDK provides tools with which you can achieve your goal. Using the specified command, you can display the value of a system variable `java.io.tmpdir`.

```
jinfo <process id> | grep "java.io.tmpdir"
```

The `<process id>` is the number of the java process for which you want to display the value of the system variable. Id of the java process you can get by using the `jps` tool, which list all java processes running on your machine.

To see all system variables of the java process, please use this command

```
 jinfo <process id>
```

All JDK tools are located in `$JAVA_HOME/bin` directory.

`java.io.tmpdir` is one of java system properties, so its value exists only inside jvm. To find out what is the value of `java.io.tmpdir` property you can also write a simple program in java. It may look something like this piece of code:

```
public class JSystemProperties {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.getProperties().list(System.out);
    }
}
```

The code above will print all java system properties, but you can modify this to print only one system property with name you pass through `args` array (using `System.getProperty(key)` method). After you compile this class you can create script (which will run compiled java class) that can be treated as Linux command to get current values of java system properties.

Comment: Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process

Comment: try to switch to root user or to the same user who started JVM

Comment: This program required import java.util.Properties. I think it make sense to edit this to System.getProperties().list(System.out);

Answer (score 14):

For black box Java applications I've deployed in the past, I have sometimes been able to find the value of `java.io.tmpdir` by executing the following command:

`ps -ef | grep java.io.tmpdir`

Particularly with tomcat apps, you may get an output like this:

`-Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp`

Answer (score 2):

For temp dir: there is a good answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/332610/where-is-the-temporary-directory-in-linux).

For all environment variable, try `env` command.

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
java -XshowSettings
```

and look for the value of "java.io.tmpdir ="

```
Property settings:
file.encoding = UTF-8
file.separator = /
java.class.path = 
java.class.version = 61.0
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/zulu17-ca
java.io.tmpdir = /tmp  # <---- HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

[Recommended](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr013.html) tool now is jcmd, use it like :

```
jcmd $pid VM.system_properties | grep java.io.tmpdir
```